# How to add each consecutive element of an array into each element of a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in the form:

```
mylist = [{1: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0},
          {1: 0.0, 2: 2.3, 3: 1.5},
          {1: 0.6, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0}]
```

And a list of the form:

```
arr = [[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 1],
       [1.0, 1.1, 3.5, 2.0]]
```

Length of `arr` is the same as that of `mylist`.
How can I add each element of `arr` into their corresponding index elements in `mylist` so that after insertion, `mylist` is of the form:

```
mylist = [{1: 0.0, 2 : 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1},
          {1:0.0, 2: 2.3, 3:1.5, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 2, 7: 1},
          {1: 0.6, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.1, 6: 3.5, 7: 2.0}]
```

Comment: So all dicts in `mylist` start with keys `1`, `2` and `3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) each sublist of `arr`, starting from `4`, and [**`update`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) each dictionary.

You associate the relevant dictionary with the relevant list by zipping them together with [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for d, extra in zip(mylist, arr):
    d.update(enumerate(extra, start=4))
```

`enumerate` normally counts from `0`:

```
>>> list(enumerate([1, 0, 0, 1]))
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1)]
```

You want it to count from `4`:

```
>>> list(enumerate([1, 0, 0, 1], start=4))
[(4, 1), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 1)]
```

Comment: What is 4 here : length of mylist or arr ?

Comment: The enumeration would normally start from `0`, but you want it to start from `4`, e.g. the first dictionary update is `{4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1}`